# ROS_STREAM relevant

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While walking through the code of nav_transform.cpp (part of robot_localization), I got confused by several output stream, it goes like this:

1. ROS_WARN_STREAM(".........")
2. ROS_WARN_STREAM_ONCE(".........")
3. ROS_WARN_STREAM_THROTTLE(".........")
4. ROS_ERROR_STREAM(".........")
5. ROS_INFO_STREAM(".........")
6. ROS_DEBUG_STREAM(".........")
7. ROS_ERROR_STREAM_DELAYED_THROTTLE(.........")

What's the difference between them?
I do appreciate it if someone can enlighten it to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261907/ros_stream-relevant/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging) clarifies things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-17**:
Somewhat related question: #q261473.

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-17**:
It helps a lot, thank you so much!